# É possível setar uma tarefa no agendador de tarefas usando php?

Tags: php, windows

Não falo de executar um php, mas criar uma nova tarefa no agendador, por meio de script php executado pelo usuário, ao navegar no site. 
É possível? Se não, qual alternativa eu tenho para fazer isso no windows? (agendar uma tarefa via php)

Comment: Dá uma lida [aqui](https://codesnob.wordpress.com/2009/05/30/creating-windows-task-with-php)